# How filtered array if this array was exist on data selected?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

this is my looping skills name

```
.suggestions__items.multiselect__tags-wrap
    .suggestions__item.multiselect__tag(v-for="skill in filteredSkillsName" :key="skill")
      | {{ skill }}
      .multiselect__tag-icon(@click="setSugesstionSkill(skill)")
```

i've tried to filtered array like this in computed

```
computed: {
   ...mapGetters("review", ["skillsName"]),
  filteredSkillsName() {
    let skills = [...this.skillsName]
    let selected = [...this.selected]
    return skills.filter(name => name != selected)
  }
},
```

and this is my method to push selected skill

```
setSugesstionSkill(selected) {
  this.selected.push(selected)
  this.setSkills(selected)
},
```

the problem is when it first click.. it works but for second and more click on another skill, it will back like first

Comment: Try `return this.skillsName.filter(name => !this.selected.includes(name))`

Comment: @Phil Thanks, it worksssssssssssssssss.. thankyou very much (y)